# PHP function doesn't pass argument to PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, syntax

Why the 2nd argument isn't passed to the query?

```
function LikesPastMonth($nMonth, $pid)
    {
        if($nMonth !== 0) {
            $n = $nMonth*-1-1;      
        } else {
            $n = -1;
        }
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xx', 'xx', 'xx', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM likes WHERE thedate = DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( LAST_DAY( CURDATE( ) ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) , INTERVAL '.$n.' MONTH ) AND pid = ?');
        $req->execute(array($pid));
        $result = $req->rowcount();
        if(!$result) {
            $result = 0;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Using a constant instead of arg and not preparing the query works.

```
define('pid','777');
$req = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM likes WHERE thedate = DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( LAST_DAY( CURDATE( ) ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) , INTERVAL '.$n.' MONTH ) AND pid = "'.pid.'"')->fetchColumn();
```

Putting the arg directly into the query doesn't work (2 examples of how i did try):

1:

```
$req = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM likes WHERE thedate = DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( LAST_DAY( CURDATE( ) ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) , INTERVAL '.$n.' MONTH ) AND pid = "'.$pid.'"')->fetchColumn();
```

2:

```
$req = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM likes WHERE thedate = DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( LAST_DAY( CURDATE( ) ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) , INTERVAL '.$n.' MONTH ) AND pid = '.$pid.'')->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: If putting the `$pid` argument into the query doesn't work even without preparing the statement, it seems that the `$pid` argument has an empty value. Throw an exception if `$pid` is empty, see if you find any errors that way. (Also, if you only want to get a count of records, use `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of actually selecting all the records.)

Answer (score 0):

From your example with the define it might not work due to the fact that you encapsulate the 777 in quotes.

Are you calling your method something like this:

```
<?php
LikesPastMonth(3, 1);
?>
```